# 14.04 only works through recovery though badly

Tags: boot, 14.04, freeze

since I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 I can't boot in any other mode than through recovery mode. If I don't, the mouse hardly works then freezes, same for keyboard. Still, after using the recovery mode my PC works but operating any function is very slow and it sometimes freezes. I had a lot of freezing incidents when still using the 12.04, so when the problem I describe above came up after the upgrade, I decided to wipe my hard drive clean with DBAN to make sure nothing would be carried over and then downloaded 14.04 from a USB drive... with the same results. The dpkg option on the recovery menu highlighted a series of errors that I'll be happy to post if anyone asks. I also got a few pop-ups early after the download warning me about problems with programs such as compiz, webapp-container or aptdaemon, among other glitches. If you could let me know how I should handle this, I'll be very grateful indeed! Fred

Comment: It looks like an hardware problem. Can you boot from a CD or USB disk and try to check the hardware and disks ?

Comment: Hi Pyrophorus, thanks for your guidance. I'll have to do a search and look up how to do what you recommend (what program should be on the CD and how to check the hardware from there) but it sounds like a good advice. Although I hope it's not the hardware giving hassle! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick hints:

1. To check the memory, boot from the install CD and select memtest (see [here for details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343114/how-to-check-for-errors-in-ram-via-linux))
2. To check the disks you can use `Disks`, the Gnome utility. More about all this [in this article.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Pyrophorus, thanks for the added advice which I followed. Although the results of those tests showed no problems related to the hardware or memory...

Comment: Too bad... (or fine if the hardware is OK). Unfortunately, I can't help you more with those errors. Sorry...