# Run memtest in terminal

Tags: memtest

I am running Ubuntu from flash drive and I would like to run `memtest` in terminal mode as multiple processes, I see file resides in boot directory but not able to execute as I get message "permission denied" not able to make the file executable either.

Comment: My `/boot` directory has no `memtest`. There is a `memtest86+.bin` though. Could you type exactly the directory name and command name? FTR you need to add `sudo ` in front of most commands where extra permission is required. Also memory tests are usually run from Grub menu and not in multi-threaded environments like Linux.

Answer (score 25):

memtest is usually run separately to a Linux kernel (selected as a boot option instead of Ubuntu), although you could download a memtest package and run it from within Ubuntu with the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install memtester
sudo memtester 1024 5
```

Running it separately to Ubuntu gives it greater access to the machine's memory, so is the preferred method.

See [How to check for errors in RAM via linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343114/how-to-check-for-errors-in-ram-via-linux) for more details.

Comment: any way to run it multithreaded instead of a single thread?