# My ubuntu 18.04 system crashes and goes to emergency mode again and again

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, grub2

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 along with windows 10 as dual boot. I rarely use windows and most of the disk space made available to ubuntu. Over the past few weeks, my system has been abrupt. Whenever memory got overloaded system freezes gets shut down and go back to emergency mode.[image: pic] I can use only the google chrome browser application If I try to open any other application like VLC media player or any programming IDE system get crashed and goes to emergency mode. It's been too painful and bringing down my work productivity due to this mishap.
I can successfully recover from emergency mode by following recovery mode steps but I again face this problem If ram memory gets overloaded or when I try to open any other applications.
Steps I followed to recover from emergency mode are booting from ubuntu live CD. cloning e2fsprog software and building it. This fixes the issue and  I can use OS again.
error message  displayed while on emergency mode from journal -xb logs are

> check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/79463e55-db4b-44ff-a896-4ad478a

[image: error]
when I do e2fsck on this space error gets fixed and I can go out from emergency mode.
But I ran into the same error again and again. I  have to follow the same recovery steps to fix this which is too painful.
sometimes I run into fsck recovery on booting by pointing ubuntu disk location and fix the error

> fsck /dev/sda7

[image]

copy of /etc/fstab [image: img]
can anyone help me to fix this issue permanently?? I thought of formatting the OS and installing a fresh one but I have important data of large size which I can't backup currently. Please someone help me to figure out to fix this error and make my system work normal as before. Thanks for reading.

Comment: How much swap space have you got? You could have faulty memory. Have you tried running memtest?

Comment: I have a 29G swap space. Yes I think the same but I can't do memtest I don't see memtest option in the grub menu my system boot with Asus uefil so I can't use bios boot to check memtest . Are there any other option to do memtest on ubuntu 18.04? I tried with live USB but I get an error while updating grub.

Comment: This link has an answer for running memtest in a terminal. https://askubuntu.com/questions/848413/run-memtest-in-terminal
There is also a link there to other answers about memtest and UEFI. Not an expert on this myself. Hope it helps

Comment: I tried with memtest-in-terminal test was successfull it perform test for only part of memory not complete. So its not best test to check memory for error. Yeah I saw other different links booting from bios to get memorytest option but I'm not able to get bios boot in my asus powered system I tweaked changes In boot menu .