# Freedesktop.org Failure

Tags: 20.04, freeze, system

I have an intermittent problem with org.freedesktop.systemd1 failing.  It seems to be happening at night (I leave my computer on at all times), and freezes the desktop to the point I have to do a hard reboot to get back in.  Here are the results from the syslog:

```
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop dbus-daemon[778]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=779 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop whoopsie[1572]: [07:26:00] offline
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1230]: dbus-daemon[1230]: [session uid=121 pid=1230] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.13' (uid=121 pid=1362 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1230]: dbus-daemon[1230]: [session uid=121 pid=1230] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop gsd-sharing[1362]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop gsd-sharing[1362]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop dbus-daemon[778]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov  2 07:26:00 garry-desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop NetworkManager[779]: <info>  [1604319961.4349] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop NetworkManager[779]: <info>  [1604319961.4358] policy: set 'Profile 1' (enp5s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1230]: dbus-daemon[1230]: [session uid=121 pid=1230] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.13' (uid=121 pid=1362 comm="/usr/libexec/gsd-sharing " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1230]: dbus-daemon[1230]: [session uid=121 pid=1230] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop gsd-sharing[1362]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop gsd-sharing[1362]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop whoopsie[1572]: [07:26:01] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop whoopsie[1572]: [07:26:01] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  2 07:26:01 garry-desktop whoopsie[1572]: [07:26:01] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Nov  2 07:26:02 garry-desktop whoopsie[1572]: [07:26:02] online
Nov  2 07:26:08 garry-desktop folding-at-home-fcole90.client[882]: 12:26:08:WU02:FS00:0xa7:Completed 62500 out of 125000 steps (50%)
Nov  2 07:26:11 garry-desktop systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Nov  2 07:27:17 garry-desktop folding-at-home-fcole90.client[882]: 12:27:17:WU02:FS00:0xa7:Completed 63750 out of 125000 steps (51%)
Nov  2 07:28:24 garry-desktop folding-at-home-fcole90.client[882]: 12:28:24:WU02:FS00:0xa7:Completed 65000 out of 125000 steps (52%)
Nov  2 07:29:31 garry-desktop folding-at-home-fcole90.client[882]: 12:29:31:WU02:FS00:0xa7:Completed 66250 out of 125000 steps (53%)
Nov  2 07:30:01 garry-desktop CRON[14304]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
```

I have searched around on both this forum and others, but have not found anyone having this exact same glitch.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try re-installation of the related packages by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common
```

Comment: That seems to have done it!  Thank you so much.
Out of curiosity, how did you know that re-installation of Gnome daemon would work?

Comment: I have determined corresponding package names by using search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ . So you can accept my answer.

Comment: Gaah!  I spoke too soon. The same error is back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing similar issue. After some reading I found that the RAM can be the culprit. Using Memtest86 I found to be failing the test. With only one RAM module the error doesn't appear for me anymore. I suggest you test your memory.

Comment: I'd test [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352363/349837)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Lets say you always login using: <kbd>USER1</kbd> 
First check: If we can login to other user. Lets say other user: <kbd>USER2</kbd> 
(Note: If you don't have another user, create a new user)
**If you are successful in login using user**  <kbd>USER2</kbd>

Probably, this is issue of config file of the user. 
Rename `~/.config` to `~/.config.bak`. 
Then, try to login to that user

You can always get shell using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login with user.