# Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet connected but no internet access

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, dns

I have an ubuntu device that is connected to ethernet "eth0" but no internet access.
below is the output for nmcli device show eth0

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:04:4B:F6:ED:8A
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     dhcp
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.23.12.11/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.23.12.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.23.220.49/32, nh = 172.23.12.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.23.220.10
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.23.220.20
IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.90.96.51
IP4.DNS[4]:                             10.90.96.52
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          NRL.Local
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::1ff5:9ebf:c1f:f06c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search nrl.local
nameserver 172.23.220.10
nameserver 172.23.220.20
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:1f:29:c7:c6:70 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:4b:f6:ed:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.12.11/24 brd 172.23.12.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 84952sec preferred_lft 84952sec
    inet6 fe80::1ff5:9ebf:c1f:f06c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:4b:f6:ed:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::204:4bff:fef6:ed88/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master l4tbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e2:a5:c6:d3:55:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: usb1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master l4tbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:09:7e:db:3e:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: l4tbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:09:7e:db:3e:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.1/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global l4tbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7c72:59ff:feea:53f2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b5:57:e9:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

```
default via 172.23.12.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
10.42.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.42.0.1  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev l4tbr0  scope link  metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.23.12.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.23.12.11  metric 100 
172.23.220.49 via 172.23.12.1 dev eth0  proto dhcp  metric 100 
192.168.55.0/24 dev l4tbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.55.1 linkdown
```

ping 172.23.12.1

```
PING 172.23.12.1 (172.23.12.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.20 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.02 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.983 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=0.983 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=0.981 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=0.989 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=1.06 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=255 time=1.01 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=255 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=255 time=0.970 ms
64 bytes from 172.23.12.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=255 time=0.945 ms
^C
--- 172.23.12.1 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 12 received, 20% packet loss, time 14029ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.945/1.018/1.207/0.079 ms
```

Comment: that `IP4.ROUTE[1]` does not look correct. Can you add `ip addr` and `ip route` info to the question?

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with freedesktop. Take a lot at this question. *https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289080/freedesktop-org-failure

Comment: @WayneVosberg, i have updated ip addr and ip route in the post

Comment: something i forgot to mention I'm trying to achieve connection in DHCP

Comment: Wow. That's a mess of NICs and routes.  What do you get when you `ping 172.23.12.1` and `traceroute 172.23.12.1` and `traceroute 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @WayneVosberg, i have a laptop connected to the same lan
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.23.12.70/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.23.12.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.23.12.1, mt = 100

Comment: I am wondering why the default route says `proto static metric 100`. Are you overriding the default routes set by dhcp somewhere?

Comment: that is what I'm trying to figure out, this device is a preconfigured one so not sure whether the vendor has any custom config, how to change it to dhcp?

Comment: check `/etc/network/interfaces` and/or the settings GUI (`gnome-control-center`) if you have it. Or, if using NetworkManager, maybe `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` or `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*` will tell you something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123219/discussion-between-gezthx-and-wayne-vosberg).

Comment: this line in nmcli device show eth0 output
"IP4.ROUTE[1]: dst = 172.23.220.49/32, nh = 172.23.12.1, mt = 0"
and
this
"default via 172.23.12.1 dev eth0 proto static"
in the ip route command output is concerning i guess