# How to install Ubuntu without a USB drive?

Tags: boot, gnome, system-installation, usb, 21.04

I installed Fedora 34 about a week ago and found out that most of the apps used .deb which Fedora doesn't support, so I was thinking about switching to Ubuntu, BUT I lost my USB drive, so does anyone know how to install Ubuntu 21.04 without USB drive? My laptop uses UEFI, so unetbootin won't work.

Comment: You can alter `grub` so it boots a ISO from a drive on the system (I use it in QA-testing on a device without working USB ports).  *Note: I didn't QA-test Ubuntu 21.04 on that device, and I know changes have been occurring in recent ISOs with live boots, so I can't guarantee it'll work, but I still believe it would*

Comment: How did you install Fedora? If you have an optical drive, then you could always burn the Ubuntu installation ISO to a DVD. It's much slower, but it'll give you an opportunity to relive the glorious 90s 

Comment: Can't you just select the boot order?

Answer (score 14):

### Booting ISO from Fedora GRUB2 Menu

The method on this page should work for booting an Ubuntu ISO from the Fedora GRUB bootloader  [20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782)  **No need for a USB here**.

**To reiterate:**

- Add the following menuentry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

  ```
  menuentry "isoname ISO" {
    rmmod tpm
    set root=(hdX,Y)
    set isofile="/[path]/[isoname].iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile toram --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
  ```

Where `(hdX,Y)` is the disk and partition the ISO is on, for example `/dev/sda3` would be `(hd0,3)`.  `[path]` is the path to the folder the ISO file is in, and `[isoname]` is the name of the ISO, for example `/isos/ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` is used if the Ubuntu ISO is located in a folder named `isos` on the root partition. `rmmod tpm` is only needed when booting in UEFI mode.

- In Terminal run:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot and select Ubuntu from the grub menu. Install as usual.
- Please let us know how this works for you.

Comment: Could you add on `toram` after the `--` just in case you accidentally wipe out your drive and no longer have the ISO present?

Comment: I am fairly new to Linux, so could you please give me an example of (hdX,Y).

Comment: @Terrance: good idea, answer edited to add `toram`.

Comment: I am fairly new to Linux, so could you please give me an example of (hdX,Y).

Comment: @Ahmed Jamal Ziyan: please let me know if my edit is clear enough.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Can you connect to my pc using TeamViewer because i keep getting errors

Comment: @Ahmed Jamal Ziyan: I do not have TeamViewer and there seems to be a cyclone happening here right now. can you describe what is happening please.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron i cant update my grub it give me an error: sudo: update: command not found

Comment: @Ahmed Jamal Ziyan: I am not as familiar with GRUB2 in Fedora as in Ubuntu. This page looks like it has good information:  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/. at this point I would backup grub.cfg and add the above menuentry by hand, rather than by using grub.d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124646/discussion-between-c-s-cameron-and-ahmed-jamal-ziyan).

Answer (score 6):

### Boot Ubuntu on Windows UEFI computer without USB or CD

For a UEFI computer, this method may be simpler than my proceeding answer:

- Use Windows Disk Management to create FAT32 partition 3GB or larger.
- Copy/Paste contents of ISO file to new partition.
- Reboot pressing F12 and select UEFI Ubuntu.
- Proceed to Ubuntu Installation.

Comment: +1 for a great method, so simple, yet it works (only in UEFI mode, but most current computers with Windows run in UEFI mode).

Comment: This method worked well for me, but note that if you are hoping to install Ubuntu on the same disk you're booting from (as I was) you might need to make sure you hit "e" to edit the boot parameters to add [`toram` on the casper line](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/casper.7.html) and also manually [unmount the boot volume](https://askubuntu.com/a/1305972/172687) to make sure it can be wiped by the installer.