# Using a Single USB Flash Drive for Both Burning and Installing Ubuntu

Tags: usb-installation

I have access to only ONE flash drive at the moment and I need to install Ubuntu on said flash drive. I've seen people on YouTube using two different USB flash drives to burn the ISO on one, and then use it to install the OS on the other flash drive. But as I said, I only have this one USB flash drive.

So, the Question is: Is there a way to use Rufus to burn my Ubuntu ISO on this USB flash drive, and then use it to fully install Ubuntu on the same USB flash drive? If not, what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Should be Rufus?

Comment: No, there isn't, for obvious reasons. If you really want to install to that one you need to boot the ISO some other way and then (1) it might not be possible; with Grub already installed (some other distro) is theoretically possible to set it to boot from an ISO residing in a recognized file system/partition and (2) even when possible it's EXTREMELY difficult. Someone asking this exact question is unlikely to be able to do any of it successfully. In summary, get yourself another USB stick, period.

Comment: So, I guess my only solution here is to use the LIVE version of Ubuntu on this one USB flash drive, correct? So now the question becomes: Can I use this LIVE version of Ubuntu on a daily basis? Will it persist? Let's say I log in to my Google Account using Firefox on this LIVE version of Ubuntu. Would I still stay logged in my Google Account the next time I boot into this LIVE version of Ubuntu? Thank you again.

Comment: No, a live session has no persistence, by definition. But you can make one *with* persistence. That said there's really no easy way, if any, to do it without some Linux distro already running. Again, get yourself another USB.

Comment: You can easily install Ubuntu to the USB drive that it was booted from, just a matter of booting the installer USB `toram`. Have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You can also boot an Ubuntu ISO directly from GRUB without the need for a USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340258/how-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-usb-drive/1357354#1357354

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes you can, the following link should have enough information for you: [to install Lubuntu Mantic to the same drive as you booted live from](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/install-lubuntu-mantic-to-the-same-drive-as-you-booted-live-from/4596)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual machine to boot from a virtual CD. Then, install to the correct USB stick in the VM.