# Install Ubuntu on HP Split 13 x2

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb, bios, usb-installation

I apologize if this is the wrong place to be asking. I usually use a Ventoy bootable drive for my Linux needs. I've recently been using an HP Split 13 x2 laptop (If you need the model no. let me know) and wanted to triple-boot it with Windows 10, Ubuntu 22.10, and either Android x86 or Windows 7 (I haven't decided yet). I have my USB drive set up and have tried multiple bootable USB software, but I cannot boot from USB. My USB drive is a Samsung bar plus 64 GB (MUF-64be4/am), and I've tried both Ventoy and Rufus as etching software.  When I press f9, or f10, or shift, when restarting, neither the windows recovery nor bios will boot from the USB. Any help, thanks!

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your question appears to be about how to boot external media on your hardware but you mention many specifics; if your Ubuntu ISO is an appropriate architecture for your device it'll boot if written correctly & you use the appropriate methods on your device to boot external media. How you do this varies on your device but this isn't a hardware site*

Comment: FYI:  What key you press is hardware specific; I have devices here that require me to press & hold specific keys whilst the device is actually turned off; the device then turns on & asks if I want to boot external media... ie. security features controlled by your firmware dictate how external media is booted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Alternatively read [How to install Ubuntu without a USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1340258/)