# Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 setup stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks" Dell Optiplex 5080

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I also ran into this issue recently ([Ubuntu Server 20.04 setup stuck at "Block probing did not discover any disks"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302392/ubuntu-server-20-04-setup-stuck-at-block-probing-did-not-discover-any-disks/1377083)). Attempting to install ubuntu-20.04.3 onto a Dell Optiplex 5080.

The following does not work for me unfortunately on ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64

Early-commands:

```
losetup -d /dev/loop0
umount /isodevice
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I have done both checking the hash in the iso file and execute the unmount of the /isodevice...

Comment: Are you attempting to install Ubuntu Server remotely? Or are you physically at the machine?

Comment: Hey Matigo, 

I am physically at the machine with a USB that I flashed via Rufus. The issue has already been addressed in the linked post, "The solution is to unmount the ISO, but there are two pitfalls here:" which the two commands do not resolve my issue as it does others.

Comment: Hmm ... I have rarely had good results with Rufus. Do you have an Ubuntu Desktop machine available? The [Startup Disk Creator](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#3-launch-startup-disk-creator) that ships in Ubuntu has always been reliable when I'm making bootable USB sticks for either Server or Desktop 

Comment: Hey Matigo, 

I currently do not have a Ubuntu Desktop machine available, this Optiplex 5080 is going to be the first install. 

As mentioned before, the issue is around unmounting the ISO but the commands that work for everyone else appears to not resolve my issue.

Comment: I do not recommend using Rufus if you did not read it's documentation. Better use Etcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also trying to install Server 20.04.03 on a Dell 5080 machine. The commands above didn't work for me either. I was looking through the BIOS and under System Configuration - SATA Operation the default was set to RAID On. I change that to AHCI and rebooted the machine. I don't get the block probing error anymore and can complete the install. I don't know why this works, but it does. I hope this helps.

Comment: I was checking through BIOS earlier and was playing around with Secure Boot/Security settings to see if something outside the scope of that reported was causing this to not pass through. Appreciate the help as you have given me the resolution to my problem.