# Ubuntu installation on Poweredge 720: "Block probing did not discover any disks"

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid, 22.04

I'm getting an error installing Ubuntu 22.04 server on a Dell Poweredge 720. Each time I try this, I get the error "Block probing did not discover any disks. Unfortunately, this means that installation will not be possible."

According to a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302392/ubuntu-server-20-04-setup-stuck-at-block-probing-did-not-discover-any-disks), the answer is to unmount the disk before installation. I found however that after executing the `umount /isodevice` command as suggested, the command returns stating that /isodevice cannot be found, so I'm not convinced that this is the issue.

There is [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377159/ubuntu-server-20-04-3-setup-stuck-at-block-probing-did-not-discover-any-disks) which suggests setting the SATA mode to AHCI, but I have no SATA devices, and the RAID controller is a PCIE device. Needless to say, the SATA mode has no effect on finding the disks.

There is evidence that the problem may be the PERC H310 MINI RAID module, which controls all disks on the device except the bootable USB. According to previous sources, it's required to have disks in RAID before the installer can see them, however I do have a raid array. The disks are configured like so:

```
Drive 0: 256GB SSD, non-RAID mode, Bootable.
Drive 1: 200GB SAS, non-RAID mode, Foreign.
Drives 2-7: 3700GB SATA, RAID mode, Online.

All drives in 2-7 are in a RAID-5 configuration.
```

So on my setup there are RAID disks, non-RAID disks, Bootable Disks, and Virtual Disks, but the installer does not detect any of them.

How can I allow the installer to see my disks?

So one thing that has been suggested to me is that I use the on-board SATA, but the disks still aren't recognized- specifically I want to install Ubuntu onto the RAID array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case was a bad battery in the PERC raid card. I swapped the card out for a H710 card, and this worked much better.