# Ubuntu goes to a black screen after grub after a ram upgrade

Tags: boot, ram

Ubuntu works fine with my old ram stick but whenever I put in this new ram stick I bought it just shows a black screen after the grub menu, regardless of configuration(including just having the new stick in without the old one). The bios detects it and it passes a diagnostic fine so i don't think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: Have you run a memory test?   (BIOS POST or power on self-test usually only test a single byte per 128kb to confirm presence of the RAM, not that it's valid & reliable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for errors in RAM via linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343114/how-to-check-for-errors-in-ram-via-linux)