# Ubuntu servers 22.04 shutsdown after some time

Tags: server, shutdown, raid

I manage a server for a friend. This server ran fine but when I tried making it go to sleep at a specific time and wake up using a cronjob, the server would not wake up using rtcwake. While trying to fix this the server started to shut down after ~10 minutes every time he turned it back on.

I tried looking for a cause using `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "panic\|error\|hang"` and `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` but that didn't show anything strange. BIOS also doesn't have any power management setting turned on.

After giving up I decided to fully reinstall Ubuntu servers 22.04 however it still shutdown after some time. We think it shuts down faster when accessed using SSH but weren't able to fully verify it.

The server has the following components:

- i7 6700k
- 16GB DDR4
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 660
- ASUS Z170 pro gaming
- 120 GB boot SSD
- 2 3TB Harddrives in RAID 1

Running kernel version: 5.15.0-47-generic

Comment: "Shutdown" as in it goes through the normal shutdown procedure or the computer suddenly switches off?  If it suddenly turns off, I would also consider a hardware problem...a loose wire, etc.  Or, I'd boot using a USB bootable disk and leave it alone to see if it shuts down...  Just to remove these possibilities from consideration...

Comment: @Ray It shuts down normally. We will try booting from a USB drive and see if it stays on.

Comment: Surely `rtcwake` (which I personally haven't used before) can't be the cause since you've reinstalled Ubuntu.  I'm not sure if your `ssh` test is valid, though.  After all, if you log in via a screen, you will need to have loaded up programs -- i.e., the GUI.  All of this doesn't load when you `ssh` in.  So, it makes sense that it will shutdown faster via `ssh`. You could consider booting into an older kernel "just for fun" / just to rule that out... Also, a [check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343114/how-to-check-for-errors-in-ram-via-ubuntu) of your memory chips (old link, but tools same)

Comment: @Ray I tried both booting from USB and tested the memory chips, both don't seem to be the issue. I feel it has something to do with the two hard drives in raid but I'm not sure what could force a shutdown.